# Как нарисовать отрезок заданной толщины на С++?

Tags: c++, графика, геометрия

Известны точки x0, y0 и x1, y1 и толщина отрезка, есть возможность только закрашивать произвольным цветом пиксель с координатами x,y. Подскажите алгоритм функции для рисования такого отрезка.

Comment: ну так а где рисовать то собрались? какой фреймворк?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch где угодно. Я хочу узнать алгоритм функции которая будет рисовать отрезок, если есть возможность только закрашивать пиксель с координатами x,y.

Comment: Пиксель может быть только закрашенным/незакрашенным? (к тому, что можно рисовать с антиалиасингом, а можно без).

Comment: Можно почитать https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Я это читал. Я не могу понять как нарисовать отрезок с заданной толщиной. Пиксель может быть закрашенным произвольным цветом. Можно конечно и с антиалисингом, но чем проще алгоритм тем лучше.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если отрезок представляет собой прямоугольник (т.е. концы не закруглены), то можно использовать обычный алгоритм для растеризации выпуклых многоугольников. Если отрезок вертикален или горизонтален, то такой случай тривиален.

Для прямоугольника под наклоном: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сортируем вершины по Y-координате
- Делим его на части по вершинам со второй и третьей координатой
- Получаем два треугольника и параллелограмм (может быть вырожденным)
- Начиная с верхней вершины, запускаем параллельно два алгоритма 
   растеризации отрезка (Брезенхема, DDA)
- Заполняем горизонтальные линии сканирования между крайними по X точками с одинаковой Y-координатой
- Дошли до одной из средних вершин - запускаем новый отрезок, и т.д.

Comment: Еще интересно было бы узнать про случай с закругленными краями.

Comment: Там уже надо растеризовать полуокружность. В принципе, у Брезенхема и для окружности есть алгоритм, да и кривой Безье можно аппроксимировать.