# Как сделать заливку наклонённого прямоугольника в Win32 API

Tags: c++, winapi, рисование

Имеются построенные с помощью LineTo прямоугольники,которые надо закрасить.Rect работает как с Rectangle,и естественно даёт возможность работать только с прямыми фигурами,не наклонными.Если же варианта с закрасом нету,можете предложить как отрисовать эти прямоугольники без помощи LineTo

```
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        HBRUSH yBrush;
        yBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 200, 0));
        SelectObject(hdc, yBrush);
        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
        FillRect(hdc, &rect, yBrush);
        HPEN yPen;
        yPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, RGB(255, 240, 0));
        SelectObject(hdc, yPen);
        Ellipse(hdc, 0, 0, 200, 200);
        HPEN rPen;
        rPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, RGB(200, 0, 0));

        SelectObject(hdc, rPen);

        MoveToEx(hdc, 40, 20, NULL);
        LineTo(hdc, 180, 160);      
        LineTo(hdc, 160, 180);
        LineTo(hdc, 20, 40);
        LineTo(hdc, 40, 20);

        MoveToEx(hdc, 20, 160, NULL);
        LineTo(hdc, 160, 20);
        LineTo(hdc, 180, 40);
        LineTo(hdc, 40, 180);
        LineTo(hdc, 20, 160);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно включить эти линии в путь (path) и вызвать [`FillPath`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Wingdi/nf-wingdi-fillpath).

```
::BeginPath(hdc);

::MoveToEx(hdc, 40, 20, nullptr);
::LineTo(hdc, 180, 160);      
::LineTo(hdc, 160, 180);
::LineTo(hdc, 20, 40);
::LineTo(hdc, 40, 20);

::MoveToEx(hdc, 20, 160, nullptr);
::LineTo(hdc, 160, 20);
::LineTo(hdc, 180, 40);
::LineTo(hdc, 40, 180);
::LineTo(hdc, 20, 160);

::EndPath(hdc);
::FillPath(hdc);
```

Comment: Как ни странно,это должно работать,но не работает.Закрашивает всё,кроме центрального квадрата,где пересекаются прямоугольники.Если эту проблему решить,то будет шикарно.

Comment: @Twip Режим закрашивания контролируется функцией `SetPolyFillMode`.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае прямоугольники можно нарисовать и закрасить с помощью функции [Polygon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-polygon).

В некоторых случаях (например, много чего под одним углом) может быть удобно рисовать именно прямоугольники в повернутой системе координат ([SetWorldTransform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setworldtransform))

[И закраска на всякий случай](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/866609/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%A1/866654#866654)

P.S. Не забывайте освобождать созданные объекты GDI